# programmatically send a microsoft teams chat message with emoji

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm posting a message in a Team channel using graph api and I want to post an emoji.

I picked up example 12 of : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

Code to post is:

```
await clientWithDelegatedToken.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Messages.Request().AddAsync(chatMsg);
```

Body content is:

```html
<div class="myDiv">3/30/2023 7:28:01 PM <br/><emoji alt ="&#x1F600"></emoji></div> <br/>
```

[image]

It returns the following error:

Code: BadRequest

Message: Unicode '' in the payload is not supported

I have only the hex values of the emojis.
How can I send an emoji?

Answer (score 0):

so simple...
The documentation is incorrect.

I replaced

string newEmoj = $"<emoji alt ="&#x{result}">";

by

string newEmoj = $"&#x{result}";

Where result is the unicode code